# How do I get tokens to create NLP model?

Tags: python, nlp, valueerror

I have a code that contains a set of list of items . I need to pass it to an NLP model which is , en_core_web_sm to tag each of the element present in the set.

```
food_item_unique = set(food_item['Source'])
```

The size of this is 131806. The NLP model accepts only a size of 1000000 with input being a string and not a set. When I convert the set(food_item['Source']) into a list(set(food_item['Source']), I have a size of 3935131. How do I input the whole of this model in order for the NLP to detect?

The NLP code is as follows:

```
doc = nlp(str(food_item_unique))
entities = []
labels = []
position_start = []
position_end = []

for ent in doc.ents:
    entities.append(ent)
    labels.append(ent.label_)
    position_start.append(ent.start_char)
    position_end.append(ent.end_char)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Entities':entities,'Labels':labels,'Position_Start':position_start, 'Position_End':position_end})
```

For this I get an error like this :

```
ValueError: [E088] Text of length 3935131 exceeds maximum of 1000000. The v2.x parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too long by checking `len(text)`.
```

Comment: _The NLP model accepts only a size of 1000000_ That isn't entirely true though, no? Did you read the entire error message? Also, please provide a [mcve] as well as the entire error output.

Comment: Hey! So, this is true. I have been getting this as my error. I do not know how to resolve this. And yes , the maximum size that it can take is 1000000. Which is why I am thinking to do it under a batch-wise process.